# WixSetup - Check pre-requisites & Adding redistributable?

Tags: wix

I am using WixSetup project for my application, which generates msi as output successfully. Now, I have to add few more details-

**Question 1: Check pre-requisites before installation:**
As a part of pre-requisites, I have to check few conditions in product.wxs file (Similar to .NET Framework 4.0)

```
<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40FULL"/>
<Condition Message="[ProductName] requires .NET Framework 4.0.">Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK40FULL</Condition>
```

How to add pre-requisite condition in product.wxs file with registry entry check?

**Question 2:   Adding redistributable packages in msi**
Also, I need to add couple of redistributable items in msi, which will be shipped with msi.
How I can add these packages in msi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first point, the WiX documentation covers this exact scenario.  See http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/read_a_registry_entry.html

With your second question, this is generally done by creating a bootstrapper bundle, which is a separate wix project that runs through a series of .msi files in sequence.  Bootstrapper projects are generally quite simple to set up.

Comment: Is this possible without bootstrapper bundle? Directly in msi setup project?

Comment: You could kick off some custom actions, but doing this would completely break the transactional nature of your installer because you're now doing work out of process and you can't safely recover from install/update/uninstall failures.  If you want to automate installing dependency MSIs, the correct way to do this is with a bootstrapper, and it's easy.

Comment: Patrick - I have accepted your answer. However, I do have one more question, similar to registry, how can I check dll present on instllation machine on particular location (e.g. %SystemRoot%\System32\inetsrv)?

Comment: It depends on what your wanting to do with those files - If all you're looking to do is see if they exist, I'd be tempted to write a c# custom action and run that early in install sequence.  If you're wanting to do things with iis, there is a wix extension which may have what you need. http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/iis/ the extension dll lives in the %wix%/bin folder.